# ansible-playbook Timer expired after 10 seconds only on some nodes but works just fine on others

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am able to ping all the servers but when I run the playbook on all the nodes it works only on some nodes and on others I get

TimeoutError: Timer expired after 10 seconds

It was working fine. It is happening from past 1 week .

Nothing has changed wrt playbook or the ansible cfg files.

```
    The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_Kh_sLm/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2853, in run_command
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    data = _eintr_retry_call(os.read, errpipe_read, 1048576)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 478, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
  File "/tmp/ansible_Kh_sLm/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/facts/timeout.py", line 37, in _handle_timeout
    raise TimeoutError(msg)
TimeoutError: Timer expired after 10 seconds

fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "cmd": "/bin/findmnt --list --noheadings --notruncate", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "fact_path": "/etc/ansible/facts.d", 
            "filter": "*", 
            "gather_subset": [
                "all"
            ], 
            "gather_timeout": 10
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "Timer expired after 10 seconds", 
    "rc": 257
}
```

Comment: What happens if you ssh to that machine and run the `cmd` (`/bin/findmnt` _etcetc_) by hand? I actually would guess that machine is under heavy I/O load causing that command to block in the kernel

Comment: when I run /bin/findmnt --list --noheadings --notruncate it executes fine. This is a new node and nothing is on this node yet. The ansible-playbook is supposed to deploy the application. So pretty much its an empty node to be clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This work-around helped me.
In /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg I set gather_subset = !all which basically only gathers minimum facts. I think while gathering facts something is messed up. So based on your requirement set the value to only gather those facts which is required for you.

Answer (score 2):

Setting gather_timeout=20 in ansible.cfg  should fix. source of the solution : 
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/43884

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be an issue with the playbooks. As @MatthewLDaniel has mentioned, try accessing the nodes that are failing via ssh. These nodes/instances might be unreachable/unresponsive over the network due to a variety of reasons. Start with checking out the instance metrics viz cpu, memory, disk and network connectivity.

> PS: Restarting the instance via AWS/GCP console usually resolves ssh timeouts issue if its a system level one.

On another note, Ansible playbooks have a default timeout of 10 seconds. You could override this by passing the `timeout` parameter while running the playbook.

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -T <TIMEOUT>
```

OR

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --timeout <TIMEOUT>
```

Comment: I am able to ssh to these nodes. I am able to do to ansible ping as well. I tried increasing the --timeout to 20,30 and even 50 and its the same result. I found out that lot of people are having the same issue from past 10-15 days. There is a thread on ansible forum as well and looks like the issue is still not fixed.   https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/43884

Answer (score 0):

set `gather_subset=!hardware` in ansible.cfg, it worked for me